# difficult limit of a sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

I came across with the following problem and I don't know how to solve it, so I need some help or any hints/steps of the solution.

**problem:** Find the limit of the sequence $\{a_n\}$, $$a_n= \left \{ \frac{n^2}{n^3+1} + \frac{n^2}{n^3+2} + \cdots + \frac{n^2}{n^3+n} \right \}$$

*my thoughts*

*usually when the limit involves sums of such form I try to find the "hidden" Riemann sum.*

*so the first step, for me, is to wright*

$$a_n= \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n^3}} $$

*,but this seems to go nowhere*

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By a simple majoration, you get that

$$n\frac{n^2}{n^3 +n} < a_n < n\frac{n^2}{n^3 +1}$$

$$\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{n^2} } < a_n < \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{n^3} } $$

And by squeeze theorem, the limit of $a_n$ is $1$